# Nameresolution from Ip-adress

Tags: networking, dns, ip

Is there other ways than DNS/NetBios to resolve name from Ip-adress? I have a device where there is no option to configure the DNS-server adress. There is a DNS-query being sent from the device, but it is going to the wrong adress and being dropped by firewall. Yet when one runs a connection-test to a network sharefolder, which is defined by ip-adress given the lack of DNS, the errorcode returns with the name of the server.

Comment: Google "hosts file" for your operating system.  The Hosts file is a static file which can contain mappings between IP addresses and hostnames and is common to the vast majority of operating systems.    It also overrides DNS.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a device where there is no option to configure the DNS-server adress. There is a DNS-query being sent from the device, but it is going to the wrong adress and being dropped by firewall.

Configure your firewall to DNAT the query packets towards whatever DNS server address you prefer.